# Email is sent without data

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, email

I got a simple email form that sends mails correctly except there is no data inside them. It also sends emails twice. What could be the cause of this?

contact.php :

```
<form class="contact-form columns_padding_5" method="post" action="mail/mail-send.php">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="contact-form-name">
                <label for="name">Naam<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Naam">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="contact-form-subject">
                <label for="subject">Onderwerp<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Onderwerp">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="contact-form-phone">
                <label for="email">Email-adres<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email-adres">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="contact-form-email">
                <label for="phone">Telefoonnummer<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" aria-required="true" size="30" value="" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefoonnummer">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <p class="contact-form-message">
                <label for="message">Bericht</label>
                <textarea aria-required="true" rows="6" cols="45" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Bericht"></textarea>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <p class="contact-form-submit topmargin_30">
                <button type="submit" id="contact_form_submit" name="contact_submit" class="theme_button wide_button color1">Verstuur bericht</button>
                <button type="reset" id="contact_form_reset" name="contact_reset" class="theme_button wide_button">Leeg formulier</button>
            </p>
        </div>


</form>
```

mail-send.php :

```
<?PHP
require_once("../phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$isValid = true;
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) 
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->addAddress("email@live.nl");   // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true);                      // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $texts = 'Er is een aanvraag op de website van website<br /> <br />
    <b>Naam:</b> '.$name.'<br />
    <b>E-mail adres:</b> '.$email.'<br />
    <b>Onderwerp:</b> '.$subject.'<br />
    <b>Telefoonnummer:</b>'.$phone.'<br />
    <b>Vragen / Opmerkingen:</b> '.$message.'<br /><br /><br />
    ';

    $handtekening = '
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; font-size:10pt;line-height:22px;">
    <tr>
    <td width="160" valign="top" style="font-family:calibri;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;">
    [contents]
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="160" valign="top" style="font-family:calibri;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;">
    <br><br>Met vriendelijke groet,<br><br>
    Helpdesk<br>
    <b>website</b><br>
    <p></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table height="120" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; font-size:10pt;line-height:22px;">
    <tr>
    <td width="250" valign="top" style="font-family:calibri;padding-left:10px;padding-top:20px;border-top: 1px #000000 dotted; border-bottom: 1px #000000 dotted;">
    E:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="mailto:info@website.nl" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #5C5C5C dotted;">info@website.nl</a><br>
    T:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="tel:0615086609" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #5C5C5C dotted;">0615086609</a><br>
    W:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="http://website.nl" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #5C5C5C dotted;" target="_blank">www.website.nl</a><br>
    </td>
    <td align="right" style="font-family:calibri;padding-right:10px;padding-top:5px;border-top: 1px #000000 dotted; border-bottom: 1px #000000 dotted;">
    <a href="http://website.nl/" target="_blank" title="Ga naar de website">
    <img src="http://website.nl/_extern/website/images/logo/logo.png" alt="Ga naar de website" style="font-family:calibri;text-align:right;margin:0px;padding:10px 0 10px 0;" border="0" width="232">
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-family:calibri;color:#a3a3a3;font-size:11px;margin-top:6px;line-height:14px;">
    <br>Dit e-mailbericht is uitsluitend bestemd voor de geadresseerde. Als dit bericht niet voor u bestemd is, wordt u vriendelijk verzocht dit aan de afzender te melden. website staat door de elektronische verzending van dit bericht niet in voor de juiste en volledige overbrenging van de inhoud, noch voor tijdige ontvangst daarvan. Voor informatie over website raadpleegt u <a href="http://website.nl" style="font-family:calibri;color: #5C5C5C; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px #5C5C5C dotted;" target="_BLANK">website</a>.<br><br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>';

    $contents = preg_replace('/\[contents]/',$texts, $handtekening);
    $mail->msgHTML($contents);
    $mail->AltBody = $texts;
    if(!$mail->send()) 
    {
        $isValid = false;
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->From = 'info@website.nl';
    $mail->FromName = 'website';
    $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true);           // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Bedankt voor uw aanvraag bij website';
    $texts = 'Geachte heer/mevrouw '.$naam.',<br /><br />
    Hartelijk dank voor uw aanvraag bij website<br />
    Wij reageren zo spoedig mogelijk op uw aanvraag.<br /><br />
    Uw gegevens worden nooit aan derden ter hand gesteld.
    ';
    $contents = preg_replace('/\[contents]/',$texts, $handtekening);
    $mail->msgHTML($contents);
    $mail->AltBody = $texts;
    if(!$mail->send()) 
        $isValid = false;
    }
    if($isValid == true) {
        $result["submit_message"] = _msg_send_ok;
    } else {
        $result["submit_message"] = _msg_send_error;
    }
        if($_POST["name"]=="" || $_POST["name"]==_def_name)
            $result["error_name"] = _msg_invalid_data_name;
        if($_POST["email"]=="" || $_POST["email"]==_def_email || !preg_match("#^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$#", $_POST["email"]))
            $result["error_email"] = _msg_invalid_data_email;
        if($_POST["message"]=="" || $_POST["message"]==_def_message)
            $result["error_message"] = _msg_invalid_data_message;   

    $result['isValid'] = $isValid;

    echo json_encode($result);
```

This is the ajax part that processes the contact form:

```
//function that initiating template plugins on document.ready event
function documentReadyInit() {
    ///////////
    //Plugins//
    ///////////
    //contact form processing
    jQuery('form.contact-form').on('submit', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = jQuery(this);
        jQuery($form).find('span.contact-form-respond').remove();

        //checking on empty values
        jQuery($form).find('[aria-required="true"], [required]').each(function(index) {
            if (!jQuery(this).val().length) {
                jQuery(this).addClass('invalid').on('focus', function(){jQuery(this).removeClass('invalid')});
            }
        });
        //if one of form fields is empty - exit
        if ($form.find('[aria-required="true"], [required]').hasClass('invalid')) {
            return false;
        }


        //sending form data to PHP server if fields are not empty
        var request = $form.serialize();
        var ajax = jQuery.post( "mail/mail-send.php", request )
            .done(function( data ) {
                jQuery($form).find('[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false).parent().append('<span class="contact-form-respond highlight">'+data+'</span>');
            })
            .fail(function( data ) {
                jQuery($form).find('[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false).parent().append('<span class="contact-form-respond highlight">Mail cannot be sent. You need PHP server to send mail.</span>');
            })
    });
```

And finally my config file where some data is set like the success/failure messages:

config.php :

```
<?php
define('_from_name', 'website');
define('_from_email', 'info@website.nl');

define('_to_name', '');
define('_to_email', 'website@live.nl');

define('_smtp_host', '');
define('_smtp_username', '');
define('_smtp_password', '');
define('_smtp_port', '');
define('_smtp_secure', ''); //ssl or tls

define('_subject_email', 'website: Contactaanvraag');

define('_def_name', 'Uw Naam *');
define('_def_email', 'Uw Emailadres *');
define('_def_phone', 'Uw Telefoonnummer');
define('_def_message', 'Bericht *');
define('_def_message_appointment', 'Aanvullende informatie');

define('_msg_invalid_data_name', 'Voer een naam in.');
define('_msg_invalid_data_email', 'Voer een geldig emailadres in.');
define('_msg_invalid_data_message', 'Voer een bericht in.');


define('_msg_send_ok', 'Bedankt voor uw bericht!');
define('_msg_send_error', 'Dit bericht kan niet worden verzonden.');
?>
```

The correct behaviour should be:

One confirmation mail to the mail the customer filled in, and one mail which the customer wrote to the company.

Now I receive two mails (with no data in them) for the company and the customer receives nothing.

Here you can see the mail is sent correctly:
[image]

And these are the two success messages I get (in json, I don't know how to decode it)

[image]

Comment: Please check out how to create a [mcve]. _Noone_ will go through that much code for a likely trivial error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    $isValid = false;
}

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->From = 'info@website.nl';
$mail->FromName = 'website';
$mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);           // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Bedankt voor uw aanvraag bij website';

$texts = 'Geachte heer/mevrouw '.$naam.',<br /><br />
Hartelijk dank voor uw aanvraag bij website<br />
Wij reageren zo spoedig mogelijk op uw aanvraag.<br /><br />
Uw gegevens worden nooit aan derden ter hand gesteld.
';

$contents = preg_replace('/\[contents]/',$texts, $handtekening);

$mail->msgHTML($contents);
$mail->AltBody = $texts;

if(!$mail->send())
{
    $isValid = false;
}
```

You're testing `if(!$mail->send())` twice.

Comment: I thought thats because hes sending 2 different emails